# Regex in word XML

Tags: javascript, regex, xml, openxml, docx

I have an xml that came from a docx in this format:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00AE2D8E" w:rsidRPr="00AE2D8E" w:rsidRDefault="00AE2D8E">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AE2D8E">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AE2D8E">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:b/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>amet</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AE2D8E">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:b/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AE2D8E">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:b/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>consecteur</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AE2D8E">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:b/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>.</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
        <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
    </w:p>
```

What is written in the docx is "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur.", However it ends up breaking due to differences in source, bold, etc.

The problem is that I need to replace the text "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur." by any other.

Does anyone know how to do this by regex? It's possible? If not, what other viable option?

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely do ***not*** want to attempt to parse OOXML with regex.

Minimally, you'll need real XML parsers and tools such as XPath:

```
normalize-space(/w:p)
```

will return nearly what you want,

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur .
```

Comment: I can already extract the text from the xml run, the problem is that I need to structure the xml again.

Comment: Then you *absolutely positively* don't want regex here.  Use a library such as Open XML Power Tools.  If you want to go it alone, you'll have to be fluent with OOXML and advanced XML techniques -- a tall order.   Last tip:  For unformatted text, your above paragraph can be simplified to `<w:p><w:r><w:t>New text here</w:t></w:r></w:p>`; just don't count on ever seeing that from another application.  Good luck.

Comment: Can I use openXML with javascript?

Comment: Eric White started a project to port his C# library to JavaScript, but you'd have to check to see whether it ever reached parity (or how close it got).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with OpenXML documents in JavaScript you should have a look at [Eric White's Open XML, SharePoint, and Office Blog](http://www.ericwhite.com/blog). He has a creen-cast that demonstrates:

- How to enables the end-user to load an Open XML application into client-side JavaScript data, modify the document, and then save that document back to the local hard drive.
- and how to generate an Open XML application based on user input in the web application.

The [code](http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/JavaScriptOpenXmlPoc.zip) is attached to this blog post. It's a bit involved and requires extra libraries - but definitively doable.

Comment: I already use a javascript library to extract the XML (mammothjs)

Comment: @Juliano see, kjhughes basically gave the same recommendation.